# Function to return a function that returns a function, etc

Tags: c#

Is it possible to define a function in a way that it basically returns itself as a delegate?

For example, if this was valid syntax:

```
public class Scrub
{
    public NotNull NotNull<T>(T value, string name)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        return NotNull; 
    }
}
```

Then I could chain method calls together like this.

```
Scrub.NotNull(param1, nameof(param1))(param2, nameof(param2)(param3, nameof(param3));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well yes, you *can*, with your own delegate declaration:

```
delegate SelfReturner<T> SelfReturner<T>(T value, string name);

static SelfReturner<T> NotNull<T>(T value, string name)
{
    if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    return NotNull;
}
```

... but it doesn't seem useful to me. Any reason you really want to do this, rather than just making three separate calls? For example, I have a `Preconditions.CheckNotNull` which returns the non-null value - I find that a lot more useful than this looks, to be honest.

As noted in comments, the above only works if all the parameters are of the same type (or all implicitly convertible to the type of the first parameter). An alternative to allow chaining with a *bit* more work would be to use a singleton instance with a generic method:

```
public sealed class NullChecker
{
    public static NullChecker Instance { get; } = new NullChecker();
    private NullChecker() {}

    public static NullChecker Scrub<T>(T value, string paramName) where T : class
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
NullChecker.Instance.Scrub(param1, nameof(param1))
                    .Scrub(param2, nameof(param2))
                    .Scrub(param3, nameof(param3));
```

With two separate methods, one static and one not (but with different names) you could remove the `Instance` part. For example:

```
NullChecker.Scrub(param1, nameof(param1))
           .And(param2, nameof(param2))
           .And(param3, nameof(param3));
```

Comment: But if `param1` was a string this would only work if `param2`, `param3`, ... were strings too, right?

Comment: I was really just curious if it was actually possible more than anything.

Comment: @IanMercer: Ah yes, you're right. I'm not sure that it's easy to fix that - it would probably be better to just have a singleton method. Will edit to indicate that.

Comment: Thanks, your update is similar to what I ended up doing except that I use two classes, one static and one not, so I can remove the `Instance` part, but keep the method names the same.

Comment: But then it might be neater to just return the `T value` and make it an extension method.

Comment: @IanMercer: Indeed, my `Preconditions` just returns the value, although I ended up *not* making it an extension method. With C# 6 you can still write things like `this.x = CheckNotNull(x, nameof(x));`

Answer (score 1):

If you make it an extension method:

```
public static class Scrub
{
    public static T NotNull<T, U>(this T value, U property, string name)
    {
        if (property == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can do:

```
test.NotNull(test.A, nameof(testA.A).NotNull(test.B, nameof(testA.B)));
```

Not quite what you wanted.